# How to make only limited letters can be typed into <input type="text" /> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

For example,to allow only digital numbers to be typed in:

```
<input type="text" id="target" />
```

Comment: Why do you have to make your question so vague as to point out in comments what you should have included in the question **in the first place?**

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`keypress()`](http://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enAU314AU317&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+keypress) event. This example prevents characters that aren't digits (0 = 48, 9 = 57).

```
$(function() {
  $("#target").keypress(function(evt) {
    if (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

See this [list of Javascript key codes](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx).

Comment: 2 issues:1.can't delete 2.can't prevent input CJK characters.

Comment: You never mentioned CJK characters for your question. Nor did you mention deleting. *sigh* common Shore question :p

Comment: For the delete part, simply allow all keypresses below 48 (except 32, space). Though IMO a better solution is to simply check the entire input after each keypress like meder's answer and flag it up accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = $('#target').val();

function isNumber ( n ) { return !isNaN( n ) }

isNumber(value) // if its '3' then true
isNumber(value) // if 3 then true
isNumber(value) // if '' then false
```

Comment: You did nothing that actually "prevents" user input.

Comment: I simply misunderstood. Try this plugin? http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: Bad news is this plugin doesn't work if you enter CJK characters.